# Disabling Internet in Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I need to disable network connection programmatically.

Is this Possible in Windows Mobile 6.5?

Answer (score 0):

you could try [IOCTL_NDIS_UNBIND_ADAPTER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee482250.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [SystemState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.status.systemstate_properties.aspx) variable. You can read from it, wire up events, and set to it.

Define a `SystemState` variable, like `ncs`:

```
  SystemState ncs= new SystemState(SystemProperty.ConnectionsCount, false);
  ncs.Changed += new ChangeEventHandler(network_Changed);
```

Now, work with the events:

```
void network_Changed(object sender, ChangeEventArgs args) {
  int connections = (int)args.NewValue;
  Console.WriteLine(connections);
}
```

A simple Microsoft example is [>>HERE<<](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.status.systemstate.aspx).